# How to convert this: "'updated_time':1375486365" to normal time?

Tags: android

I am developing a Facebook app. I fetch update_time and it is like this:

```
updated_time":1375486365
```

How can I convert this into a normal time in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The time you get is epoch time.

Check this http://www.epochconverter.com/

You will have to use this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

and pass the epoch time in millis. In your case multiply by 1000.